# Can't get my nav bar to stick to top after scrolling past header?

Tags: jquery, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var distanceFromTop = $('#sticky_menue').scrollTop();
        if (distanceFromTop >= $('#header').height())
        {
            $('#sticky_menue').addClass('fixed');
        }
        else
        {
            $('#sticky_menue').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#sticky.fixed {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
```

```html
<!-- Nav Bar -->
    <div id="sticky_menue">
     <div id="nav_bar">
      <div id="logo_nav"> Logo </div>
      <ul> 
        <li><a href="link">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="link">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="link">Social</a></li>
        <li><a href="link">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="link">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/32atL9pc/

I'm trying to get the nav bar to stick to to the top after I scroll past header?

Comment: Are you able to use `position: sticky`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution, using native js :

**CSS additions and modifications :**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#sticky_menue {
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}
#sticky_menue.normal{
    position:relative;
}
#sticky_menue.fixed {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}
```

**JS :**

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {

    var contentDiv = document.getElementById('content_area');
    var navDiv = document.getElementById('sticky_menue');
    var navDivHeight = navDiv.offsetHeight;
    var distance = contentDiv.getBoundingClientRect().top;

    if (distance <= navDivHeight) {
        navDiv.classList.replace('normal', 'fixed');
    }
    else if (distance > navDivHeight) {
        navDiv.classList.replace('fixed', 'normal');
    }
});
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/32atL9pc/16/**

Answer (score 0):

Your css provide a class for *#sticky.fixed*, which is never met.

Try *.fixed*, or *#sticky_menue.fixed*